# interface node failing to launch

Tags: ros, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a Phidgit InterfaceKit 8/8/8 USB interface.
I have been able to get the package installed, but I get an error when I try to launch the package. The USB interface is recognized as verified by lsusb.
Below is the error that I receive when running this line of code:

*roslaunch phidgets_ros interface_kit.launch*

and the error:

*started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.12:50386/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES
/
interface_kit (phidgets_ros/interface_kit.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.12:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[interface_kit-1]: started with pid [21545]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/phidgets_ros/src/phidgets_ros/interface_kit.py", line 45, in 
from phidgets_ros.msg import Float64Stamped
ImportError: No module named msg
[interface_kit-1] process has died [pid 21545, exit code 1, cmd /home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/phidgets_ros/src/phidgets_ros/interface_kit.py __name:=interface_kit __log:=/home/ros-root/.ros/log/81778158-4a18-11e2-9c53-c86000cc26ff/interface_kit-1.log].
log file: /home/ros-root/.ros/log/81778158-4a18-11e2-9c53-c86000cc26ff/interface_kit-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
*

Now, /home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/phidgets_ros/src/phidgets_ros/interface_kit.py exists... but I'm not sure about the next part of the message "ImportError: No module named msg"...

Any suggestions on why this isn't launching? Any suggestions about this error?

I appreciate the help.

Joe

EDIT:
I installed from here:
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgetspp_c_api.html
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgets_py_api.html
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgets_ros.html#InterfaceKit_ROS_API

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50828/interface-node-failing-to-launch/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you done:

```
rosmake phidgets_ros
```

and maybe also:

```
roscd phidgets_ros
make
```

Looks like the messages defined by the package have not been built yet.

Also, please tag your questions, that makes it easier for people to find them (thus making it more likely that you'll get an answer :)

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2012-12-20**:
Yup. That was the issue. For some reason it was failing to make but not throwing an error.
The permissions for the "phidgets_ros" folder were set to user permissions and not for read/ write for the "adm" group. ROS wasn't able to "make" with out the proper folder permissions.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2012-12-20**:
I'll remember to set the tags in the future. I didn't realize that search didn't search the text of the threads as well as the tags. Thanks for the advice.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2012-12-20**:
Now to figure out how to record data while echoing /interface_kit/116807/sensor/1 (which is the one I currently have it plugged in to... Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2012-12-21**:
Glad I could help. Just one more thing, if the answer has solved the problem you were having, could you please mark it as correct (by clicking on the checkmark on te left han side, below the answer heading).

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2012-12-21**:
Done and done. Didn't know that's what that was about. Thanks again.